# Get the name of the album from a tagged photo using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos

I am able to grab album name and photos uploaded by the user using the graph api.

When I use "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=".$access_token", I get all the tagged photos of the user. Is there a way to get the name of the album of a photo, which has not been uploaded by the user but by his friend?

Thanks

Comment: you'd need `https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/photos?access_token=<access_token>`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get that directly, but using the "link" attribute you can quickly suss it out, as seen in this example:

```
"link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150154222339657&set=a.358879884656.199726.249427954656&type=1"
```

That `set` parameter and `fbid` tell you much more about the photo.

You can view more details about the photo by going to the page for it. It will tell you the position in the album, though it still won't have the album:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/10150154222339657
```

You *can* however determine the album id from the `set` parameter, the album id is the between the `a.` and the second `.`, so in this example the album id is 358879884656

So, the album info would be available at:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/358879884656
```